# Check if method already is in instance in object?

Tags: python, class, oop, attributes, instance

I'm trying to see whether an instance of an attribute already exists for my object. As you can see below, I want to do something if my `Dog` object has a certain attribute, via the `do_something_if_has_aged` method. How can I check whether a certain attribute has already been declared? Usually you would check for existence with something like this, which returns `False`:

```
obj = None
if obj:
    print(True)
else:
    print(False)
```

Here's my minimum reproducible example:

```
>>> class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def add_years(self, years):
        self.age += years
        self.has_aged = True
    def do_something_if_has_aged(self):
        if self.has_aged:
            print("The dog has aged and is %d years closer to death" % self.years)
        else:
            print("The dog hasn't aged, apparently.")


>>> dog = Dog('Spot', 3)
>>> dog.age
3
>>> dog.do_something_if_has_aged()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#193>", line 1, in <module>
    dog.do_something_if_has_aged()
  File "<pyshell#190>", line 9, in do_something_if_has_aged
    if not self.has_aged:
AttributeError: 'Dog' object has no attribute 'has_aged'
>>> dog.add_years(1)
>>> dog.age
4
>>> dog.do_something_if_has_aged()
The dog hasn't aged, apparently.
```

Clearly the dog *has aged*, though.

I apologize if the title doesn't reflect what I'm trying to convey below; I'm new to OOP.

Comment: Your condition is the wrong way round: you should do `if self.has_aged`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than test for the attribute, set a default value on the class; if an instance attribute is missing Python looks for a class attribute instead:

```
class Dog:
    has_aged = False  # default for all instances
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    def add_years(self, years):
        self.age += years
        self.has_aged = True  # sets an instance attribute
    def do_something_if_has_aged(self):
        if self.has_aged:
            print("The dog has aged and is %d years closer to death" % self.years)
        else:
            print("The dog hasn't aged, apparently.")
```

(note that I had to invert your test, if `self.has_aged` is *true* you want to go into the first branch, not the other way around).

Or you can set a default value for the attribute in the `__init__`:

```
class Dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.has_aged = False
    def add_years(self, years):
        self.age += years
        self.has_aged = True
    def do_something_if_has_aged(self):
        if self.has_aged:
            print("The dog has aged and is %d years closer to death" % self.years)
        else:
            print("The dog hasn't aged, apparently.")
```

You can also test if an attribute is present with the [`hasattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#hasattr):

```
def do_something_if_has_aged(self):
    if hasattr(self 'has_aged') and self.has_aged:
        print("The dog has aged and is %d years closer to death" % self.years)
    else:
        print("The dog hasn't aged, apparently.")
```

or by using the [`getattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr) with a default value:

```
def do_something_if_has_aged(self):
    if not getattr(self 'has_aged', False):
        print("The dog has aged and is %d years closer to death" % self.years)
    else:
        print("The dog hasn't aged, apparently.")
```

However, testing dynamically for attributes should not be the first option you pick; having a class default is much cleaner.

Comment: What's the advantage of `has_aged` being a class variable instead of an instance variable (defined in `__init__`)?

Comment: @JosieThompson: there is only one copy of the variable (so a memory advantage); why give all instances the attribute when the default could just be stored on the class?

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you are looking for the [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) built-in function:

```
>>> class Dog(object):
...     pass
...
>>> a = Dog()
>>> hasattr(a, 'age')
False
>>> a.age = 7
>>> hasattr(a, 'age')
True
```

In your case, you can modify as follows:

```
def do_something_if_has_aged(self):
    if hasattr(self, 'has_aged'):
        pass # do your logic
```

Answer (score 1):

I would rewrite the `__init__` method to include `self.has_aged = False` to avoid having to do inspection:

```
class Dog(object):
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
        self.has_aged = False # Starting value so it is guaranteed to be defined (unless explicitly deleted).
```

Now, the rest of your class should work as written. However, if you want to see if an attribute has been defined on an object, you can write this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def set_bar(self):
        self.bar = True # Define the attribute bar if it is not yet defined.

    def is_bar_set(self):
        return hasattr(self, 'bar')
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if using `hasattr` is perfectly fine, but in case you are looking for a quick fix for you code, you can do initialize the variable as false before hand:

```
class Dog:
  has_aged = False
```

and also the fix your condition as i think it should be reversed:

```
def do_something_if_has_aged(self):
  if self.has_aged:    # instead of not self.has_aged
    print("The dog has aged and is %d years closer to death" % self.years)
  else:
    print("The dog hasn't aged, apparently.")
```